# GraphQL in React through Apollo client goes through loading phase but never loads data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I use query

```
  const ALL_PERSONS = gql`
query {
  allAuthors {
    name
    born
    bookCount
  }
}`
```

This query works in graphql playground but not in code. In code result.data is empty

```
const result = useQuery(ALL_PERSONS)
```

in postman it also works

Answer (score 0):

I just misprinted booksCount , there is no such property, so everything broke so.
There were errors 14 frames collapsed and error 400 bad request